# ReactJS state updates on second onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a beginner to React; I understand that setState is asynchronous, but I don't understand why in the example pen below the box below the refresh is not done immediately, and only updates after the second character is input.

Codepen: **(updated to link to correct pen)**
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/odZrjm?editors=0010

Portion:

```
// Returns only names matching user's input
filterList = (term) => {
    let finalList = []
    for (let x = 0; x < this.state.names.length; x++) {
      if (this.state.names[x].toLowerCase().includes(term)) {
        finalList.push(this.state.names[x])
      }
    }
    finalList.sort()
    return finalList
}

// Returns the name list as string
listNames = () => {
    let filteredNames = [], filter = this.state.filter.toLowerCase(), names = ""
    if (filter === "") return "Enter filter chars"
    // Generate filtered array with only names matching filter
    filteredNames = this.filterList(filter)
    // Build and return comma-separated list of filtered names
    names = filteredNames.join(', ')
    if (names.length === 0) return 'None found'
    return names
}

handleChange = (event) => {
    let result, alert = 'alert-primary'
    result = this.listNames()
    this.setState({
      filter: event.target.value,
      namesList: result
    })
}
```

If I replace the line "result = this.listNames()" in handleChange with just "result = 'test'" then it updates immediately. Can you please explain why it does not when I call the functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It occurs because you are calling the listNames method before this.state.filter is set, thus reaching:

```
if (filter === "") return "Enter filter chars"
```

Here's a working pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gzmVaR?editors=0010

Answer (score 0):

This is because `listNames()` is being called before setState

Answer (score 0):

when you call handleChange method, it can't find 'this' scope.
so 'this' is undefined and can't call this.listNames().

solution:

use        onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}

instead of onChange={this.handleChange}